# How do you save an integer to NSUserDefaults?

Tags: iphone, ios

Does anyone know how I would go about saving my high score integer to NSUserDefaults so I can load it later?

Answer (score 59):

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:HighScore forKey:@"HighScore"];
```

… to get it back:

```
NSInteger highScore = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"HighScore"];
```

This is explained very simply in the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults%5FClass/Reference/Reference.html#//apple%5Fref/occ/instm/NSUserDefaults/setInteger%3AforKey%3A).

Comment: You are right, of course.  But Googling (and finding useful two-line solutions like your's) is MUCH faster than digging through Apple's documentation.  You could argue that, by Googling, I'm either lazy, or efficient..!

Answer (score 11):

More generally, you can save Foundation class objects to the user defaults, *e.g.*:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:highScore] forKey:@"kHighScore"];
```

and

```
NSInteger highScore = [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"kHighScore"] intValue];
```

But the convenience method is there for taking in an `NSInteger` directly.

I prefer to use the more agnostic `-setObject:` and `-objectForKey:` because it more cleanly separates the object type from access to the dictionary.