# how to save an NSInteger in NSUserDefaults

Tags: objective-c, nsuserdefaults, nsinteger

I am trying to save an NSInteger (label) into NSUserDefaults but I have not found a way to do this is it even possibel

Saving the data

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:label forKey:@"key1"];
```

Retrieving the data

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
label = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"key1"];
[super viewDidLoad];
```

Comment: You need to add some more information here about the problems you're having. What doesn't work here? Try adding some NSLog statements demonstrating the problem and show the output.

Comment: That code is correct. What's your question?

Comment: Given that the above code works, and you stated that it was an issue with adding the numbers, I'm closing this. Please feel free to ask a new question with the addition issues that you are running into, if that's your core problem.

Answer (score 6):

I think you forgot so `synchronize` your settings. Try this:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:label forKey:@"key1"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

Comment: ok i guess then my problem isn't the saving but the adding numbers. if i have an int called label and make it so that label + 1 is that workabel code?

Comment: @MattMühlemann: I don't understand your question. I think it's better if you ask a new one as John suggested

Answer (score 4):

What you are doing works perfect

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:HighScore forKey:@"HighScore"];

NSInteger highScore = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"HighScore"];
```

duplicate:
[How do you save an integer to NSUserDefaults?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1482097/iphone-sdk-save-a-integer-to-nsuserdefaults)

Read the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsuserdefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html) on this topic, it looks like you don't understand NSUserDefaults