# How to save a high score

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsuserdefaults

How do I go about saving a high score using nsuserdefaults and displaying it on the main menu. Currently my score label code looks like this.  BTW I am using objective c.

```
_scoreLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02lu", (unsigned long)_enemies.count];
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you save an integer to NSUserDefaults?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1482097/how-do-you-save-an-integer-to-nsuserdefaults)

Answer (score 2):

this is how you save the score

```
if(HighScore<ScoreNumber)
{
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setInteger:ScoreNumber forKey:@"Save"];
}
```

this is how you get the score,so you need to convert int to string..and display a string in a label.

```
HighScore=[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"Save"];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can save your highScore using `NSUserDefaults` `setInteger`. The code for saving an integer into `NSUserDefault` goes here.

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:HighScore forKey:@"HighScore"];
```

Now you can set the highScore from `NSUserDefault`. The code for retrieving Integer from NSUserDefault goes here.

```
[_scoreLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"HighScore"]]];
```

Comment: you should flag as a duplicate instead of posting this info as an answer.